# Deriving Distributions and Covariance from Joint Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, covariance, moment-generating-functions

**Q: Suppose random variables  and  have joint moment generating function:**

[image]

**What are the distributions for X and Y and their covariance, Cov[X,Y]?**

I am unsure how to derive the individual distributions when given just the moment generating function. Also, I am unsure how to derive the individual distributions when it is not known whether X and Y are independent/dependent random variables.

Would really appreciate it if someone can provide an answer to the question and how to evaluate the covariance. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When $M_{X,Y} (s,t)$ splits as  a product of a function of $s$ and a function of $t$ it follows that $X$and  $Y$ are independent. Also, $M_X (s)=\frac 1 {2-s}$ and $M_Y(t)=(\frac 2 3 )^{4}(\frac 3 {3-t})^{4}$. By independence the covariance is $0$. I will let you write down the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @AlexWilliams $X$ takes non-negative interger values with $P(X=n)=\frac 1 {2^{n+1}}$.